# How to decouple the UI object identifiers from the test scripts while writing Selenium tests

Tags: selenium

I'm planning on writing some test scripts for a J2EE app using Selenium. The PageObject pattern sounds pretty good as it allows a clean seperation between test logic and implementation. How can I maintain the identifiers for each UI element in the app, coding them within the PageObject doesn't sound too good. Creating a repository of all the UI elements and their identifiers - whether it be id,xpath or other - within the app sounds nice, what would be best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

[Tellurium](http://code.google.com/p/aost/) seems to be a good fit for your need.

It allows you to define logical page components, such as:

```
ui.Container(uid: "GoogleSearchModule", clocator: [tag: "td"], group: "true"){
 InputBox(uid: "Input", clocator: [title: "Google Search"])
 SubmitButton(uid: "Search", clocator: [name: "btnG", value: "Google Search"])
 SubmitButton(uid: "ImFeelingLucky", clocator: [value: "I'm Feeling Lucky"])
}
```

And then reference them throughout your tests.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Looking forward to a .NET version

Comment: Check out Seleno for .NET. For MVC, this provides you with full integration with existing Display Model objects.